# Как хранить древовидную структуру атрибутов сущности в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой проектирования БД.

Проблема такая, что у меня есть сущность, например какой-либо товар. У этого товара есть вложенные атрибуты, т.е. атрибуты зависимы. Внешне наглядно это выглядит так:

Товар

- Атрибут №1
- - Под атрибут №1
- - Под атрибут №2
- - - **Под Под атрибут №1**
- Атрибут №2
- Атрибут №3

Как мне хранить такую древовидную зависимость в MySQL? Пользователь может запросить **Под Под атрибут №1** и я должен выдать все сущности у которых есть **Под Под атрибут №1** при этом показать всё дерево родителей. Как это можно сделать? С помощью справочников? Читал про Closure Table, не совсем понял поможет ли это мне или нет.

Вложенность уровней может быть и 3 и 5 и 7, но точно не более 10. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Читать `Nested Sets`, `Materialized Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-псевдокод, для наглядности

Тут товары с ID и прочими описаниями

```
create table Wares(
    id_ware INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
)
```

Тут атрибуты с ID и прочими описаниями

```
create table Attributes(
    id_attribute INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
)
```

Тут привязка товаров к первоуровневым атрибутам

```
create table WareToAttributeRelations(
    id_ware INT FOREIGN KEY TO (Wares:id_ware),
    id_attribute INT FOREIGN KEY TO (Attributes:id_attribute),
)
```

Тут все остальное дерево атрибутов

```
create table AttributToAttributeRelations(
    id_attribute_parent INT FOREIGN KEY TO (Attributes:id_attribute),
    id_attribute_child INT FOREIGN KEY TO (Attributes:id_attribute),
)
```

Comment: это больше, чем дерево. Тут можно любой ориентированный граф изобразить.